# GUI does not start on boot

Tags: 12.04, boot, xorg

Ubuntu 12.04 does not start x after boot up.
Worked until now without any problem, and last shutdown was clean.

After text log in I can run `startx`, but no tray and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> does not working.

Command `startx` run my default gnome classic and gnome statup scripts also runs.

How to restore to start X automatically?

Answer (score 3):

After boot,try to start desktop manager:

```
 sudo service lightdm start
```

then check if lightdm is default desktop manager:

```
 cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
```

if not, edit file with:

```
/usr/sbin/lightdm (or /usr/bin/lightdm)
```

Reboot and lightdm should start.

Comment: After boot up the command 
`sudo service lightdm start`
start up my X as expected with panels and all customization working.

File /etc/X11/default-display-manager contains /usr/sbin/lightdm, needed not to change anything. The executable file exist in that folder.

After reboot X does not start automatically, still requires to manually `sudo service lightdm start`.

How to make lightdm service to start automatically ?

Comment: try to reconfigure package: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`. If not working, try to delay startup of lightdm: in `/etc/init/lightdm.conf` before command `exec lightdm` add `sleep 2` (or more). It seems to be a issue related of use of SSD.