# Can't login after running startx

Tags: 12.04, login, gui

Think I have totally messed my system up, and it's a case of lesson learned for not reading things correctly maybe.

For some reason my GUI stopped loading after logging into ubuntu 12.04,  think I have misinterpreted this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302788/gui-does-not-start-on-boot)

```
Command startx run my default gnome classic and gnome statup scripts also runs.
```

As I ran this using sudo startx but was presented with a blank screen, so I restarted and tried to login as my user but it just loops back to the login page every time now

I don't know what to do to get access back into my laptop

If anyone could help I would be so grateful

Edit

Followed this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/407720/cannot-login-to-ubuntu-after-startx-command) and now I can login, lesson learned, but still no GUI

Comment: Try `sudo lightdm` to get the gui.

Comment: Got an error message saying failed to use bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager, do you have appropriate permissions?

Comment: It was sudo, and you have an admin account?

Comment: I'm the only account if that makes sense, I tried sudo service lightdm start but then it says job is already running

Comment: Using `sudo` to run `startx` will cause your `.Xauthority` file to get owned by `root` - there are many previous questions about this e.g. [Ubuntu gets stuck in a Login Loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: Looking in /etc/x11/default-display-manager it is set as /usr/sbin/lightdm

Comment: Try `sudo service lightdm restart` then Ctrl+Alt+F7

Comment: Just goes to a blank screen

Comment: Also looking at my Xauthority file, it's 0 as it's file size, so it's empty? And also no $DISPLAY ENV set after printenv