# Lenovo Think Pad never boots up with Linux( Ubuntu)

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, windows-8, lenovo

I bought a Lenovo think-pad and installed Ubuntu. It came by default with Windows 8. I booted him from USB with linux and wiped off windows. I did some coding on the machine, every thing went well till I restarted the machine. It never boots up with Ubuntu now. I don't want to re-do all my work. Can some one explain me, how to fix this.

Comment: "_It never boots up with Ubuntu now_" could you clarify what you mean by this ? What do you see on screen ? Any error messages ?

Comment: It doesn't show any errors.

Comment: Do you see anything at all on screen ? Is so, what ?

Comment: Does it boot up with something *else*? If it does not show errors (other than the error of **not booting your OS**) does it instead boot back into Windows? Do you see **Grub**? We can help more the more information you provide. Good luck!

Comment: It asks for BIOS password  and it also  stays interrupt if you want to stop normal start-up and then it goes blank. When we try to shut down the system, light screen of ubuntu progress comes up and then shuts down. Can some one help. I have a deadline coming up.

Comment: it just flickers and does nothing.

Comment: I did Alt shift F1 and then ran   sudo service lightdm start  .   It opened UI but when I restarted it doesn't  show the UI again. I have tpo repeat the proces.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/302788/gui-does-not-start-on-boot

Comment: Try running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` from the terminal (Alt + Shift + F1).